# How to show 'Deployment in progress' page?

Tags: .net, git, azure, deployment

I was wondering how can I show the user browsing my website a **deploy in progress** page when I'm deploying to Azure. Just a simple message saying '*Sorry, we are currently undergoing a release, please check back in a few minutes*'.

Is there an **app setting** I should set in order to achieve this? Or is there a slightly different approach I should consider?
Thanks.

Comment: Currently what happens when you load on deploy ?

Comment: Nothing really. But I basically want to avoid the scenario where somebody would access a page during deployment. I want to show the user another page instead ('deploy in progress'). It would be ideal if that could happen automatically after applying a webconfig setting. Deployment is already linked to Azure through git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's an easier way. Ended up adding an app setting defaulted to false. I check it's value in the home controller and redirect to a **deploy in progress** view when the value is true. Changing the app setting value is done via deployment script.